# cordova hybrid Email client app

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app

I have been asked to create an Email client for Android/ios.

I have been looking at Cordova to create this email client app. 
There is a cordova-plugin-email-composer plugin to send mails, but I am wondering how to receive Emails through Imap, and store them.

Can anyone advise on this? Or maybe suggest an alternative for Cordova to create a hybrid mail client app?

Comment: I think question asking for advice is beyond the scope of the site. Maybe you could rephrase your question a bit and include what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sp0T. True, I am looking for advice from fellow programmers. Any advice on how to handle this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP (sending mails) is the easier task in cordova, even with mailto:yourname@mailserver.com?subject=...&body=... in the href-attribute in HTML5 you can send an e-mail on mobile devices cross plattform.What you need is a library for IMAP and/or POP3 access in cordova.

I look for the same plugin in Cordova, to write an OpenSource-App as Messenger replacement for WhatsApp using existing Mailserver. This has many advantages:

1. This OpenSource-App could use existing Infrastructure for sending and receiving messages and attachments as mails. No need to set up new server infrastructure
2. Messengers like WhatApp are popular and users like that quick communication style.
3. There is no need to provide my communication to DCC (Data Collecting Company) like Facebook for WhatsApp. Everyone could use the mail server she/or he prefers.
4. You can receive messages and send messages on a desktop computer with a regular mail client, cross-plattform and cross devices

[Basic concept used from AT6FUI](http://at6fui.weebly.com/messenger.html)